# Can't dynamically load Facebook like buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, xfbml

I have a webpage which will dynamically load the next page when you scroll to the bottom, once the new page loads I want to be able to render all the Facebook like buttons that are new but not all the ones that have already been rendered.

I am at a bit of a loss as to where I have gone wrong with this and any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Javascript code:

```
$('.fb-like:not(.fb_edge_widget_with_comment)').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).attr('id', 'ajax-fb-like');
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('ajax-fb-like'));
    $(element).removeAttr('id');
});
```

Facebook like button code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://url.com/" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: a good place to search for this http://facebook.stackoverflow.com. you may as well call FB.init() again and it will re-render all the elements on the page

Comment: I am trying to avoid re-rendering all the elements, as after a while there will be a lot that will require re-rendering. I would much rather just render them once each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your like buttons to XFBML and use `FB.parse()` to make your buttons dynamically.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: I see where I went wrong, I was using the HTML5 code for Facebook like button rather than the XFBML code, thank you :)